# ConnectivityManager.getBackgroundDataSetting() deprecated, what to use instead?

Tags: android

Previously one could use:

```
ConnectivityManager.getBackgroundDataSetting();
```

to check if the user had background data setting = true. This method is now deprecated:

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html
```

The docs say to use:

```
ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

instead, which returns a NetworkInfo object, but what's the equivalent check in NetworkInfo then?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `getActiveNetworkInfo()` is `null`, you do not have a network connection, either because the device does not have a network connection, or because user settings (e.g., bandwidth caps) prevent your app from having a network connection.