# What is the alternative to getBackgroundDataSetting

Tags: android, android-wifi, connectivity

When I tried to use:

`connectivity.getBackgroundDataSetting();`

Eclipse says it is deprecated. So, is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the docs for [ConnectivityManager.html#getBackgroundDataSetting()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getBackgroundDataSetting())

> This method was deprecated in API level 14. As of ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH,
>   availability of background data depends on several combined factors,
>   and this method will always return true. Instead, when background data
>   is unavailable, getActiveNetworkInfo() will now appear disconnected.

So above API 14, just check that `getActiveNetworkInfo()` is not null and use that as your boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the doc :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html

Use the new one :

```
ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

UPDATE

And its a little different from the old (deprecated) method. Take a look at CommonsWare's answer :

[ConnectivityManager.getBackgroundDataSetting() deprecated, what to use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051263/connectivitymanager-getbackgrounddatasetting-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)